# Tags: verisimilitude vs. realism

Tags: discussion, tags

1 question has both [verisimilitude](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verisimilitude) and [realism](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/realism), and for each of these tags there's 1 more question with only that one without the other.

To me, both of these tags actually look like "**internal-consistency**", so we could rename both of them, in order to prevent someone to think incorrectly they instead refer to "the real life".

Better ideas or insights?

Comment: Relevant: [Are the verisimilitude and realism tags necessary?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3244/1204)